# Flutter Provider "The getter 'length' was called on null."

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have Provider where I am taking initial value of List as null. At very first instance of opening app, i get error "The getter 'length' was called on null." as I am using this provider in home widget. How can I consider value 0 if List is null?

```
class BagProvider with ChangeNotifier {
List bag_items = null;
```

I am listening it this Consumer.

```
Consumer<BagProvider>(
              builder: (_, bag, __) => Badge(
                    value:
                        bag.bag_items.length,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.shopping_cart,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CartScreen.routeName);
                      },
                    ),
                  ))
```

Comment: initialise the variable with empty list not null. like this `List bag_items = List();`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Consumer<BagProvider>(
              builder: (_, bag, __) => Badge(
                    value:
                        bag.bag_items?.length,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.shopping_cart,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CartScreen.routeName);
                      },
                    ),
                  ))
```